# replacing np.float64 nan in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas dataframe as below:

```
>>> df.head()
            timestamp  count_200  count_201  count_503  count_504   mean_200    mean_201  mean_503  mean_504  count_500
0 2020-09-18 09:00:00     4932.0       51.0        NaN        NaN  59.501014   73.941176       0.0       0.0          0
1 2020-09-18 10:00:00     1697.0        9.0        NaN        NaN  57.807896   69.111111       0.0       0.0          0
2 2020-09-18 11:00:00     6895.0        6.0        2.0        1.0  54.037273   98.333333      33.0    1511.0          0
3 2020-09-18 12:00:00     2943.0       97.0        NaN        NaN  74.334353   74.268041       0.0       0.0          0
4 2020-09-18 13:00:00     2299.0       43.0        NaN        NaN  70.539800  102.302326       0.0       0.0          0
```

fillna does no replace the NaN

```
>>> df.fillna(0)
              timestamp  count_200  count_201  count_503  count_504    mean_200    mean_201    mean_503  mean_504  count_500
0   2020-09-18 09:00:00     4932.0       51.0        NaN        NaN   59.501014   73.941176    0.000000     0.000          0
1   2020-09-18 10:00:00     1697.0        9.0        NaN        NaN   57.807896   69.111111    0.000000     0.000          0
2   2020-09-18 11:00:00     6895.0        6.0        2.0        1.0   54.037273   98.333333   33.000000  1511.000          0
3   2020-09-18 12:00:00     2943.0       97.0        NaN        NaN   74.334353   74.268041    0.000000     0.000          0
4   2020-09-18 13:00:00     2299.0       43.0        NaN        NaN   70.539800  102.302326    0.000000     0.000          0
```

But if we access just one row, fillna on the resulting series works as expected:

```
>>> df.iloc[0]
timestamp    2020-09-18 09:00:00
count_200                   4932
count_201                     51
count_503                    NaN
count_504                    NaN
mean_200                  59.501
mean_201                 73.9412
mean_503                       0
mean_504                       0
count_500                      0
Name: 0, dtype: object

>>> df.iloc[0].fillna(0)
timestamp    2020-09-18 09:00:00
count_200                   4932
count_201                     51
count_503                      0
count_504                      0
mean_200                  59.501
mean_201                 73.9412
mean_503                       0
mean_504                       0
count_500                      0
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

What is going on here?

```
>>> df.iloc[0,3]
nan
>>> type(df.iloc[0,3])
<class 'numpy.float64'>
```

Pandas recognises as a na:

```
>>> df.isna()
     timestamp  count_200  count_201  count_503  count_504  mean_200  mean_201  mean_503  mean_504  count_500
0        False      False      False       True       True     False     False     False     False      False
1        False      False      False       True       True     False     False     False     False      False
2        False      False      False      False      False     False     False     False     False      False
3        False      False      False       True       True     False     False     False     False      False
4        False      False      False       True       True     False     False     False     False      False
```

But with numpys inbuild function this can be fixed in pandas:

```
>>> df.head().apply(np.nan_to_num)
            timestamp  count_200  count_201  count_503  count_504   mean_200    mean_201  mean_503  mean_504  count_500
0 2020-09-18 09:00:00     4932.0       51.0        0.0        0.0  59.501014   73.941176       0.0       0.0          0
1 2020-09-18 10:00:00     1697.0        9.0        0.0        0.0  57.807896   69.111111       0.0       0.0          0
2 2020-09-18 11:00:00     6895.0        6.0        2.0        1.0  54.037273   98.333333      33.0    1511.0          0
3 2020-09-18 12:00:00     2943.0       97.0        0.0        0.0  74.334353   74.268041       0.0       0.0          0
4 2020-09-18 13:00:00     2299.0       43.0        0.0        0.0  70.539800  102.302326       0.0       0.0          0
```

Is this expected, I can't find this documented. What am I missing? Is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df[df.isna().any()] = 0
```

you can use this,pandas lib can be confusing,as for one functionality you have many type of things you can do,i generally try all and dont stuck in one,tell me if this is working or atleast what is it doing.

Comment: I guess this is a better solution than my apply. But I still don't understand why it would recognise something as nan but not fill it in fill na.

Comment: what you were doing will create a temporary memory and will fill the values,that is why use "inplace = True".

Comment: No, inplace=True is generally discuraged in the docs and this wasn't the problem here. The output of df.fillna(0) contains NaNs as shown.

Answer (score 3):

```
df.head()

             timestamp  count_200  count_201  count_503  count_504   mean_200    mean_201  mean_503  mean_504  count_500
0 2020-09-18  09:00:00     4932.0       51.0        NaN        NaN  59.501014   73.941176       0.0       0.0          0
1 2020-09-18  10:00:00     1697.0        9.0        NaN        NaN  57.807896   69.111111       0.0       0.0          0
2 2020-09-18  11:00:00     6895.0        6.0        2.0        1.0  54.037273   98.333333      33.0    1511.0          0
3 2020-09-18  12:00:00     2943.0       97.0        NaN        NaN  74.334353   74.268041       0.0       0.0          0
4 2020-09-18  13:00:00     2299.0       43.0        NaN        NaN  70.539800  102.302326       0.0       0.0          0
```

**Replacing `NaN` with `0`**

```
df.fillna(0)

             timestamp  count_200  count_201  count_503  count_504   mean_200    mean_201  mean_503  mean_504  count_500
0 2020-09-18  09:00:00     4932.0       51.0        0.0        0.0  59.501014   73.941176       0.0       0.0          0
1 2020-09-18  10:00:00     1697.0        9.0        0.0        0.0  57.807896   69.111111       0.0       0.0          0
2 2020-09-18  11:00:00     6895.0        6.0        2.0        1.0  54.037273   98.333333      33.0    1511.0          0
3 2020-09-18  12:00:00     2943.0       97.0        0.0        0.0  74.334353   74.268041       0.0       0.0          0
4 2020-09-18  13:00:00     2299.0       43.0        0.0        0.0  70.539800  102.302326       0.0       0.0          0
```

It is working fine for me.

Use `inplace=True` to apply the changes to dataframe

```
df.fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

Pandas version I'm using is

```
print(pd.__version__)
0.23.0
```

Please restart IDE/python kernal

Check and update pandas version (if required)

Comment: thanks for these tips, i'm sure they are usefull to some struggling with Pandas and the intricacies of fillna, but this issue is more caused by different handling of the different nan types in numpy and pandas. Unfortunatly jus tpasting the test to Stackoverflow doesn't do that justice. I tried to specify the type to make this clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I can't seem to recreate the error, if I copy your provided df and use `pd.read_clipboard()` to turn it into a df, then `df.fillna(0)` gives the expected results for me.

When you provide the return from df.fillna(0), is that the actual return? Or are you printing the df. If so, remember to use the `inplace=True` parameter.

Comment: No i'm pasting the returned df, as indicated. Yes, clipboard doesn't do it justice, as pandas just used a more sensible nan type when loading the df then. You need to look at the type information. I can't recreate it my self other than shipping the pickle of the pandas dataframe, as this is definitly reproducible in that way.